# What is the possessive of Saint John's?

Tags: possessives

We have a city here in Canada named Saint John's. It is always spelt that way; the **'s** is part of the name (this must be a very unusual case, I'm not sure).

What would be the correct way to refer to something the belongs to it? 'Saint John's' mayor', 'Saint John's's mayor', or ... ?

Comment: I just punt: "...[the] mayor of St. John's..."

Comment: From the EL&U archives: *[Possessive of a word that is already possessive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2933)*

Comment: You might ask your local newspaper what they use. My guess would be just "Saint John's".

Answer (score 4):

I'll be honest with you: most English speakers wouldn't know what to do here.  None of the style guides I checked gives clear guidance for this situation.  If we were to follow the closest applicable suggestion, to add 's for any singular proper noun, even if it ends with s, we would get

> St. John's's mayor

Interestingly enough, my spell checker doesn't even mark this as wrong, although it's clearly ungainly as heck.

The best suggestion I found was, "Avoid awkward possessives" -- which in this case means you should write:

> The mayor of St. John's

If you absolutely must use the possessive, I'd go with either

> St. John's' mayor

or simply

> St. John's mayor

More in-depth discussion of this here:  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/89705/possessive-form-of-a-proper-noun-ending-in-a-plural-noun-ending-in-s

Comment: Good answer. I was just in the middle of starting one of my own and will now stop. :) It doesn't matter what is "correct" if it looks incomprehensible. So, just rephrase it to avoid the problem. As for the name of the city, the [St. John's website](http://www.stjohns.ca/living-st-johns/your-city/st-johns-history/city-name) says, among other things, that "Prowse maintains that it would have been known as the "harbour of St. John’s Island" which could account for the possessive form, St. John’s, instead of St. John."